# Javascript - Unable to reload iframe

Tags: javascript, android, html, iframe, android-webview

I have an Android application with webview. there are two pages with an iframe that shows pdf using google docs. My problem is that loading this: `javascript:document.getElementsByTagName(\"iframe\")[0].src = document.getElementsByTagName(\"iframe\")[0].src;` works only for one of those pages. The strange thing is that there is no problem if I other url when changing the src (for example a picture). What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was in the src url. I had to parse it before I use it.
So we should always check what url we use for the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the right index for the 2nd frame?

```
javascript:document.getElementsByTagName(\"iframe\")[1].src = document.getElementsByTagName(\"iframe\")[1].src;
```